# Regular Expression for Job Status (Autosys)

Tags: regex, extract, status, jobs, autosys

I have an output like below:

```
Name1 12/26/2013 12:05:04  12/26/2013 12:05:08  SU 34066553/1 0      
Name2 12/26/2013 12:05:10  12/26/2013 12:05:14  SU 34066553/1 0      
Name3 12/26/2013 12:05:04  12/26/2013 12:11:13  FA 34066553/1 5      
Name4 -----                12/26/2013 11:06:06  AC 34066553/0
```

then I need to parse a status (i.e `SU, FA, AC and so on`).
Below fragment shows only first record.

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\b
```

How can I get all inputs here to check and validate it.
 I'm using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Thanks.

Comment: Well, `\b[A-Z]{2}\b` does match all your needs. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ9aF0). Don't forget to match all by setting the `g` modifier

Comment: That's a root cause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work

try this :

```
\b([A-Z]){2}
```

result

SU, SU, FA, AC

Comment: this matches any word starting with two capital letters, like `FOO` or `ANYTHING`, but the question clearly wants only two-letter words